# Alphabetize in Perl

Tags: perl

here is the prompt I have: Write a Perl program that reads in an arbitrary number of strings from the command line and
displays them sorted alphabetically. Here's what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

# read command line arguments


# verify correct input and display error and quit if input is valid
# (1) quit unless we have the correct number of command-line args
my $numargs = string $num_args = $#ARGV + 1;
if ( $num_args != 2 ) {

   exit;
}
if ( $num_args > 2 ) {
   my $num_args eq string
     print "Enter multiple random strings of letters, separated by spaces: ";
   exit;
}


# (2) If we get multiple command arguments, assume they are
# separate strings of random letters
my @string = ARGV

  if ( $string eq ARGV ) {
   my $string = ARGV;
}


# sort strings
my @sorted_string = sort @string;

# display sorted string

print "Here is your sorted list: "@sorted_string "\n";
```

The errors I'm getting is about naming, but my professor said I'm close. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Sobrique, Thank you so much for your edits! Unfortunately I'm still getting naming and "explicit package" errors.

Comment: Yes, you will. I've just reformatted your code for clarity and indentation, I haven't changed it's semantics. You're asking for someone to rewrite your code, and as it stands - it's not perl. Get to a point where it'll _actually compile_ and you can explain what you don't understand and you'll have a better starting point for asking questions.

Comment: *"my professor said I'm close"* Did they really? Well I can reassure you: you're really not. If you're supposed to have been learning Perl for a while then it looks like you've absorbed pretty much nothing. You need to read your notes again thoroughly and start *understanding* what you're being told. You won't learn a thing if we do your homework for you.

Comment: If you care to actually understand this stuff and the class is not sufficient, you might want to buy a copy of the book _Learning Perl_. And as a word of advice from someone who trains developers as part of his job, please learn to communicate clearly. A big part of most technical jobs is to ask the right questions. Once you are the one being asked, you will see that it is very hard to answer them without sufficient knowledge about the problem or a crystal ball. Always include details. Always include input and output. Often the act oft trying to find the right words already solves the problem.

Comment: @simbabque: I didn't know you did training. No matter what people say about Perl's object-oriented facilities, I think it's the best language by far to teach OO principles. It provides all the tools you need to build an obiect-oriented structure without abstracting it all behind language concepts. I was a dreadful C++ programmer until I had done a few years of Perl, after which I understood what all that stuff *actually did*. It's a shame in a way that `Moose` was necessary, but in the spirit of making "hard things possible" it 's pretty much essential.

Comment: @Borodin I train apprentices (the 3 year job training we have in Germany) for what is called _IT specialist/software development_ (_Fachinformatiker/Anwendungsentwicklung_) and the language at `$work` is Perl. Others from around here have found me on the `$work` social media. That place says what else I do. ;) Anyway, I agree that the underlying concepts are very obvious with Perl's native OO. I read that very old book about them once, and it is essential I think. But Moose has its merits and I can't imagine working without it. It also feels very easy to grasp for trainees I have to say.

Comment: @simbabque: "that very old book"?

Comment: @Borodin _Object Oriented Perl_ by Damian Conway. It was released in 1999. I consider that very old for a programming book. But it's still highly current.

Comment: @simbabque: I don't think I've ever read that one, but I have a lot of respect for Conway.

Answer (score 6):

OK, look. Stack overflow isn't a 'fix my homework' site.

Your code - it's not perl. `use strict;` `use warnings;` actually tells you what is wrong, but you've got *so many* errors it can be hard to follow.

So - begin at the beginning:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

# verify correct input and display error and quit if input is valid
# (1) quit unless we have the correct number of command-line args
my $numargs = string $num_args = $#ARGV + 1;
```

What did you *intend* this to mean? Because it errors with *just* this line already, so you can stop there and not bother looking at the rest of your code (for now, but it has more errors).

You:

- declare `$numargs` using `my`.
- then you use a function called `string` (which doesn't exist) on a variable called `$num_args` - which also doesn't exist.

Perhaps you meant:

```
my $num_args = @ARGV;
```

Or you could just use `@ARGV` in a scalar context whenever you need `$num_args`.

But there's further problems with your code, that suggest you don't really understand:

- Semicolons are statement separators. End of each line, typically. You're missing a bunch.

That means as far as perl is concerned:

```
 my $num_args eq string
   print "Enter multiple random strings of letters, separated by spaces: ";
```

is a single line of code:

```
my $num_args eq string print "Enter multiple random strings of letters, separated by spaces: ";
```

Which doesn't make a lot of sense.

- `$` denotes a scalar variable. `@` an array. But `perl` automagically knows the difference between "string" and "number" when you operate on it. `$string` and `@string` are not the same thing. They're completely different variables (but confusingly named, so don't do that).
- Context is important. If you use `@ARGV` in a *scalar* context (e.g. as if it's a single value) it will return the numeric count of number of entries.  See: [perldata context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context)
- `ARGV` isn't anything. `@ARGV` is an array containing the values of the command line arguments. See: [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)
- Barewords aren't cool. Quote things that are supposed to be strings. If they're functions/subroutines make sure they exist - `string` doesn't, because perl doesn't actually have a "string" type - it has has scalars.  (See [perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html)
- You have a logic error I think. You test for `$num_args != 2` and exit - so ... basically can only ever have two arguments to your code. That's at odds with  your comment.

I'm not going to give you the answer (you'll probably get marked down, because your professor can google too), but as a hint - you can just operate on `@ARGV` and given your spec, can have about one line of *actual code* to do what you want. (Two maybe, if you want to give a message about lack of input too)

So backtrack a bit. Think about what you're *actually* trying to do. You know your 'arbitrary string from command line' is `@ARGV`.

Comment: I see. I apologize for asking the question incorrectly! Perl is clearly new to me - I'm sure this is supposed to be a simple/straightforward prompt but I'm still confused by arrays.

Comment: OK. Well, about the best i can offer is: Read through [`perldoc perldata`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) - and then ask another question about what you're having trouble understanding. If possible, give a sample code snippet that illustrates what you're having problems with.

Comment: *"`ARGV` isn't anything"*    `ARGV` is actually a filehandle.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has the look of someone who is trying random things in the hope that one of them will work.

```
if ( $num_args != 2 ) {
  exit;
}
```

This is valid Perl. It will exit your program if `$num_args` doesn't equal 2. But your definition of the problem told you to write "a Perl program that reads in an arbitrary number of strings". So why exit if you're not given exactly two strings?

```
if ( $num_args > 2 ) {
  my $num_args eq string
  print "Enter multiple random strings of letters, separated by spaces: ";
  exit;
}
```

This doesn't compile. I think you're missing a semicolon at the end of `my $num_args eq string`. But even then it makes no sense. What do you think `string` is? And `eq` is a comparison operator - you might be trying to use it for assignment here.

But, above that, it makes no logical sense. In the previous section, you exited the program if `$num_args` wasn't equal to 2. And now you're checking to see if `$num_args` is greater than 2. The only possible value that `$num_args` can have at this point is 2. And 2 is never going to be greater than 2.

```
my @string = ARGV

if ( $string eq ARGV ) {
  my $string = ARGV;
}
```

Something else that can't even compile. There's another semicolon missing and `ARGV` is a filehandle, not the array you seems to think it is.

You need to step back and take a closer look at the question. And think logically about the solution. Programming is about breaking problems down into smaller steps. If you find yourself typing stuff at random in the hope that something will work, then it's time to take some time off. Go for a walk around the block to clear your head.

Perl's mission is to make jobs like this simple. The code that solves your problem is a single line.

```
say foreach sort @ARGV;
```

But please don't submit that as your solution unless you can explain how it works.

Comment: If `eq` is equivalent (no pun intended) to `==` for strings, maybe we should push for `e` as a new assignment operator for strings in equivalent to `=`. Would make for more fun in obfuscation contests...

Comment: @simbabque I was once told on LinkedIn that "eq" was Perl's string assignment operator. I'm convinced that the person who told me this was serious, but I have no idea how any of his code ever worked.

Comment: Ouch. I see. Maybe that person is now a teacher at OP's university? On a different note, your solution doesn't need the `foreach` because `print` is fine with a list, but it might need a `say` or a `join ' ',` or setting `$,` because since we're sorting command line args, there are no newlines in the input, and everything comes back as one long sorted string without separators.

Comment: Yeah. I meant `say` instead of `print`. But as I was typing I realised there was a good chance the OP was using a Perl without `say`. But now I realise I don't care.